# Multiple x axis on the bottom of chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm trying to show multiple x axis on the bottom of my chart.
  I started to add the axis with layout.xaxis.position to show them stacked but they start getting over the chart.
  Then I set layout.margin.pad to 50 and I got the result I wanted for the first axis only.

Is there a way to do this for the remaining ones? Or is this a bug?

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    autoexpand: false
  },
  xaxis2: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.1
  },
  xaxis3: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.2
  },
  yaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    zeroline: false,
    rangemode: 'tozero'
  },
  showlegend: false,
  autosize: false,
  width: 450,
  height: 220,
  margin: {
    l: 10,
    r: 10,
    b: 60,
    t: 10,
    pad: 40
  }
};
```

Chart Image with mad paint skills.

[image: Chart Image]

[Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/vascocc/pen/KeqyZx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codepen, the problem is simply that `position` cannot be set to a `negative` value, hence you can move the axes up, but now down. I have two solutions for you, it involves positioning the axes using the `ticklength`, as a sort of hack, please refer the below example, implement it and let me know if your issue is resolved!

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"name":"Atual","x":["May 28","May 29","May 30","May 31","Jun 01","Jun 02","Jun 03"],"y":[115.4,122.4,102.3,105.1,28.9,29.6,114.2]},{"name":"Atual-1","xaxis":"x2","x":["Jun 04","Jun 05","Jun 06","Jun 07","Jun 08","Jun 09","Jun 10"],"y":[69.6,71.1,78.9,72.5,24.5,25.2,69.2]},{"name":"Atual-2","xaxis":"x3","x":["Jun 11","Jun 12"],"y":[0.08,0]},{"name":"Atual 77777","xaxis":"x3","x":["Jun 11","Jun 12"],"y":[109.9,2.9]},{"name":"Atual-3","xaxis":"x4","x":["Jun 11","Jun 12"],"y":[8.6,0.2]},{"name":"Atual 2","xaxis":"x4","x":["Jun 11","Jun 12"],"y":[0.06,0]}]');

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    autoexpand: false,
    visible: false
  },
  xaxis2: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.1,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    gridcolor: "#000000"
  },
  xaxis3: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.2,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    gridcolor: "#000000"
  },
  xaxis4: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    gridcolor: "#000000"
  },
  yaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    zeroline: false,
    rangemode: 'tozero'
  },
  showlegend: false,
  autosize: false,
  width: 450,
  height: 220,
  margin: {
    l: 30,
    r: 0,
    b: 70,
    t: 0,
    pad: 0
  }
};

var layout2 = {
  xaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    autoexpand: false,
    visible: false
  },
  xaxis2: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.1,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    tickcolor: "#eee"
  },
  xaxis3: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0.2,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    tickcolor: "#eee"
  },
  xaxis4: {
    fixedrange: true,
    domain: [0,1],
    anchor: 'free',
    overlaying: 'x',
    position: 0,
    layer: "below traces",
    ticklen: 30,
    tickwidth: 1,
    ticks: "outside",
    tickcolor: "#eee"
  },
  yaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    zeroline: false,
    rangemode: 'tozero'
  },
  showlegend: false,
  autosize: false,
  width: 450,
  height: 220,
  margin: {
    l: 30,
    r: 0,
    b: 70,
    t: 0,
    pad: 0
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false, showTips: false, staticPlot: false});

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', data, layout2, {displayModeBar: false, showTips: false, staticPlot: false});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
<div id="myDiv2" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
```

Comment: I think is a good workaround. Just one question? You set first axis visibility to false. Was it for the tick lines that appear on the first axis? Is it possible to change them? I kind of need the first axis too.

Comment: @VascoCC You can simply, enable the `xaxis` by setting `visiblity: true`, then set the same properties for `tick`, as it is in the other `xaxes`, also please do let me know if the issue is resolved completely!!

Comment: Thanks, @Naren Murali, your solution works great for me. I posted this question in plotly forum too and they will support negative positions in v2. For the time being, I'll use this instead.

Comment: @VascoCC Nice one! we need negative positioning for axis, You're welcome!